# Ender 3 Calibration Cube Fail + Can't Print Circles

Tags: print-quality, creality-ender-3

After noticing that my ender 3 couldn't print a 'perfect' circle I decided to use a [calibration cube](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1278865) to see if that could be the issue. These were my results:

[image: X Y Z]

I did have some successful prints before noticing these problems but it would be great if anyone could help/find a solution.

I think it may be because of the belts tension as I had accidentally over stretched it by putting it over the wheels instead of under: is it worth getting a new belt then?

I use 20% infill, with triangle pattern in cura, using the standard 0.4mm nozzle.

## Edit

After doing a [different testprint](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3090144) and measuring, it revealed that both had an accurate 20mm Y and Z, but only an 18.5mm X. Might I have destroyed my belt when I mounted it overstrained?

## Edit2:

After purchasing a new X belt, the calibration cube was much closer at 19 x 20 x 20. But still not at a good enough tolerance for my liking. Additionally, when printing a cylinder, two relatively flat edges were printed with it either side (perpendicular to the x-axis).

Comment: what are your slicer's settings for "number of top layers"?

Comment: @Trish I used Cura, would Slicer be better? For cura my top/bottom thickness is 0.6 mm; (the layer was 0.1 mm); the top thickness was 0.6 mm and top layers was 6

Comment: cura is perfectly fine. Any infill? what's the nozzle diameter?

Comment: @Trish 20% triangle infill. I don't know about the nozzle diameter: default for ender 3 1.75mm

Comment: Mind updating photos of the new print? the 18.5 for 20 seems consistent as you said in chat.

Comment: @jb7852 - I think the 1.75mm is the filament diameter ... it should be stamped directly on your nozzle what size it is. I'd suggest it's probably 0.4mm.

Comment: This looks like missing steps or binding in x direction. Does the carriage run smooth with depowered steppers (M84)?

Comment: My prints look almost erily identical on the cube test and i am getting bad circles. what was the best solution? did you ever fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your top layer looks like you need to add additional top layers and there are signs of a slight bit of over-extrusion in that top layer (red). On the other hand, it looks like the top layer is not sliced nicely resulting in gaps and holes (yellow), which might be a fault of the test print.

[image: Z, defects marked]

The X on the file you used is not centered, resulting in the off look in the print.

I suggest you try a different calibration print before starting to tinker with the hardware, for example [this](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3090144).

I suggest to use concentric only for the top layers and instead rely on a simple Zig-Zag pattern for the intermediate layers, as this usually generates a better connection to straight walls.

## EDIT1:

After considering the miss-dimension in X only, you might want to look to [calibrate your X steps](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/3344/calibrating-steps-order).

The stretching of the belt might be an issue, but you might get away *easy* if you just check belt tension and manage to get it right again.

As I have an ender-3 myself, I know you might need to [flash](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6399/recalibrating-home-position) [fresh](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6657/export-firmware-as-a-hex?noredirect=1&lq=1) firmware to get the ability to change the steps/mm.

## EDIT2:

The 19x20x20mm cube sounds like the new belt did fix a lot of the dimensioning problem, but the steps/mm might be slightly off - or we have to trace down SOME mechanical error in the movement path. As a 140mm long test print also had a 1mm offset, a steps/mm error should be out.

After examining the machine with jb [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83007/ender-3-calibration-cube-fail), the bearing on the X-belt seemed to stick a tiny bit on one side.

[image: Ender3 X-tightener/bearing]

Turning the large bolt of the assembly in an attempt to disassemble it without a wrench to hold the self-securing nut on the far side seemed enough to lessen the pressure on the core of the bearing, allowing it to spin freely. In addition, the belt was a little loose.

Comment: I 100% agree. Do you have any idea why my main issue was occurring i.e. the X wasn't centered/how squares came out rectangular and circles as ovals. I feel like it must be a belt problem

Comment: The x side is 18 mm though as if its squashed

Comment: @jb7852 The X of the  calibration cube from [Thingiverse that you printed](http://thingiverse.com/thing:1278865), is not in the center in the STL! I see the X off centered in my test cubes also. Note that this does not explain the 18 mm in size!

Answer (score 4):

First, check that the calibration part you have is actually a cube. Maybe you downloaded a trick 'calibration cube' model. Cura will show he overall dimensions of any model which it is slicing.

Ignore any print quality issues first off. A hollow calibration cube is mainly used to check the X/Y/Z motion and so long as you print at a sensible (slow) speed), the other parameters shouldn't have much effect (so long as the first layer is OK, and you get within 30% of the right extrusion).

If the calibration cube is within +/- 0.5mm on each side, it's probably good. Under/over extrusion, caliper technique, etc, can explain this sort of variation, and you might want to use a bigger test part like [this star on my thingiverse account](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2566871) once you think you're close.

The 'steps per mm' setting is determined within the firmware, it is part of how your printer consumes G-code. For a delta printer, for example, there is some fancy maths to combine X/Y/Z into the motor movements. This means that you can't change steps/mm in Cura, you need to either change the firmware defaults and 'reset to factory settings', or modify the parameters in EEPROM by sending G-code.

Seeing too small a calibration part (for a Cartesian printer) can easily be explained by problems in the printer's motion system:

- Stepper missing steps due to jerk or acceleration too high
- Stepper missing steps due to binding/friction in the bearings (Send `M84` to idle the stepper motor, and move X by hand)
- Teeth missing on the drive belt (may show up on a diagonal 'bar' print)
- Loose drive pinion (maybe backlash on the flat on the spindle means the problem is greater on small parts) - see below
- Flex in the drive mechanism (e.g. belt mount to traveller is loose)

An annoying feature of a lot of these problems is that for any particular repetitive sequence of steps, you might see a very consistent result. Even thought to problem is something being badly adjusted, it gives the impression that the problem is calibration.

The drive wheel is held in place with a grub screw, see this diagram from the Anet-A8 assembly diagram.

[image: Anet X-drive]

Comment: the inadequate first test cube model was what I suspected, but both having X=18/18.5 instead of 20 as in the model is a good sign something is off.

Comment: @Trish So after purchasing a new X belt, the calibration cube was much closer at 19 x 20 x 20. But still not at a good enough tolerance. Additionally, when printing a cylinder, two relatively flat edges were printed with it either side (perpendicular to the x-axis), thoughts?

Comment: Similar to this https://www.reddit.com/r/3Dprinting/comments/2zw4zn/flat_sides_on_my_circle_prints_i_have_calibrated/

Comment: It feels relatively smooth, no bumps anything

Comment: Would tightening the belt in some way help e.g. on the motor or the point pictured here. https://imgur.com/gallery/6nvme2n

Comment: @jb7852 I created a chat for this question. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83007/ender-3-calibration-cube-fail